# Can't access internet but can ping

Tags: release-freya, networking

I have just installed Elementary OS on my laptop, and everything including the WiFi is working. I can do

```
ping google.com
```

and it also works (shows correct IP). However, when I try to actually go to `google.com` it wouldn't load (loads forever). This is same for every request, including doing things like

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I can access my router's page though. What would be a reason for it to be happening?

(Acer Aspire One 32 bit)

Comment: Which browser did you use when you tried connecting to Google? Have you tried using some other browser? Do other internet-dependant applications (like Geary for example) work? Also, I can't figure out can you execute `sudo apt-get update` or can't because you said that the "same thing happens". Same thing as you got when pinging Google or the same thing you got when trying to open Google?

Comment: @r3bl `apt-get update` will get stuck because it can't download anything. It's strange that later I switched to another WiFi hotspot (same router, different SSID) the internet suddenly worked. One thing to notice is that the original SSID I connected to is not in English (Unicode). It might be the problem.